# Configure debug version of OpenSSL for Windows

Tags: windows, debugging, openssl

I've built the release version of OpenSSL 1.1.1c libraries without a problem, but I cannot create the Debug version.

According the documentation I used:

```
perl Configure --debug VC-WIN64A
```

However the Perl % (ActiveState) doesn't recognize the argument debug.
When I use -d, the build alone will switch to the debug execution mode.

Somewhere on Internet I found the form:

```
perl Configure debug-VC-WIN64A
```

However, I couldn't confirm it with the documentation.

What is the proper format for the Perl?

Comment: Ping @mattcaswell.

Comment: @query - Did you figured this out ??

Answer (score 4):

-d does not work with windows builds... The original poster had it correct, he just had the parameters in the wrong order...

On Windows, to build a debug version, you do it like:

perl Configure VC-WIN64A --debug

I just verified it just now, as I'm building 1.1.1l as we speak. Omitting that flag, defined NDEBUG, but specifying that flag defines DEBUG. Original poster specified --debug before VC-WIN64A, but it must be specified after.

Answer (score 1):

> according the documentation I used:
>
> ```
> perl Configure --debug VC-WIN64A
> ```
>
> However the Perl % (ActiveState) doesn't recognize the argument debug.
>   When I use -d, the build alone will switch to the debug execution
>   mode.

According to [Compilation and Installation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation) on the OpenSSL wiki, you should use `-d`. See [Configure Options](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation#Configure_Options)

---

> Somewhere on Internet I found
>
> ```
> perl Configure debug-VC-WIN64A
> ```
>
> however, I couldn't confirm it with the documentation.

Use `Configure LIST` to show the targets.

```
$ ./Configure LIST | grep VC
VC-CE
VC-WIN32
VC-WIN32-ARM
VC-WIN32-ARM-UWP
VC-WIN32-ONECORE
VC-WIN32-UWP
VC-WIN64-ARM
VC-WIN64-ARM-UWP
VC-WIN64A
VC-WIN64A-ONECORE
VC-WIN64A-UWP
VC-WIN64A-masm
VC-WIN64I
```

---

You might also be interested in [`NOTES.WIN`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/NOTES.WIN), which are the build and install notes for Windows. The notes do not list `--debug`.

It looks like `--debug` is detailed in [`INSTALL`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/INSTALL) file. `--debug` works on Linux for OpenSSL 1.1. Maybe it does not work on Windows, or maybe it used to work with a version like OpenSSL 1.0.

(I don't have a Windows machine with Perl, so I can't run the tests for you).